# How can I add an mp3 file to a ContextMenuStrip or does it have to be wav format?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

This is my code in Visual Studio 2013 .vb

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles       Button1.Click
    ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Button1, 0, Button1.Height)
    ContextMenuStrip1.MaximumSize = New Size(100, 150)   'Genesis - ContextMenuStrip1
End Sub
```

I have a button that is a drop down with 50 choices. Genesis has 50 chapters 
so I have 50 audios, one for each chapter.  I want the person to be able to 
scroll down the list and chose:

button (Genesis)
Genesis 1
Genesis 2
Genesis 3 etc...

I cant find anywhere where I can add an audio once the ContextMenuStrip1 has been clicked.

I am new at visual basic and this is my first app.

Comment: Use it's click event.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will research click event and how I should write it.

Comment: If this is your first app and you want to play an mp3 file I would recommend using the Windows Media Player object because its very easy to learn and use. Here is a quick tutorial which teaches you how to play mp3s in VB.Net: http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2013/05/how-to-make-mp3-player-in-vbnet.html

Comment: Im not sure if I should have just asked another question instead of editing my own question with an answer and question....sorry if thats not proper forum rules.   Well I see you can answer your own question or supply an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so I have use this code to play my ("wav") file after I converted from 
mp3 - I'll try Joey's suggestion another time -

```
    Private Sub Genesis1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Genesis1ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim mySound As Media.SoundPlayer
    sPath = "C:\Users\admin\Music\wav\Genesis01.wav"
    mySound = New Media.SoundPlayer(sPath)
    mySound.Play()
End Sub
```

This plays my sound file at the drop down menu Genesis 1 (thankfully).
Thank you for your input.